# SQL Column Does Not Exist Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, authentication

Okay, so basically I asked this  little earlier today but we didn't get to the root of the problem and a lot of speculation was clouding the solutions. I have a program that currently needs to check a users inputed 'Gamer-Tag' from `RegUserName.Text` and compare that with Gamer-Tags stored on the SQL Table `PersonsA` which is in the `Members_Details` Database.

When the code is ran I receive the below error;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column 'Gamer_Tag' does not belong to table
>   PersonsA.

However, Gamer-Tag IS in the Table; It's the second Column in the table. The Server is MS SQL Server and when I use the 'SQL Server Management Studio' I can clearly see the table & columns. From there all SQL Codes in relation to the `Gamer_Tag` column work flawlessly, so it's definitely in the database.

Here's the code which is called when a button is pressed. This code 'calls' the Function with the error.

```
Dim dbManager As New DatabaseManager() 'My Class Where The Functions Are

        If dbManager.CheckGamerTagisMember(RegUserName.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Gamer-Tag is NOT A Member.")
            GoTo Ender
        Else
            MsgBox("Gamer-Tag is A Member.")
            GoTo Ender
        End If
```

And here's the Function which contains the Error;

```
 Public Function CheckGamerTagisMember(ByVal gamertag As String) As Boolean

Connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source =" & My.Settings.ServerIP & ";Initial Catalog=Members_Details;Integrated Security=False;User=" & My.Settings.UserName & ";Password=*******;")
            Connection.Open()

Dim gamertagDatSet As New DataSet()

usersDataAdapter.FillSchema(gamertagDatSet, SchemaType.Source, "PersonsA")

usersDataAdapter.Fill(gamertagDatSet, "PersonsA")

Dim table As DataTable = gamertagDatSet.Tables("PersonsA")

        For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim storedgamertag As String = table.Rows(i)("Gamer_Tag").ToString.ToString '<-------- ERROR 

            If (storedgamertag = gamertag) Then
                gamertagDatSet.Dispose()
                Connection.Close()
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        gamertagDatSet.Dispose()
        Connection.Close()
        Return False
    End Function
```

What could cause this problem? I've checked obvious spelling and spacing, the firewall's off and the Column is without a doubt there. The function code was adapted from my SQL Login function, which worked without any issues, so I'm puzzled on why this isn't working.

Here's a screenshot from MS SQL Server Management Studio showing the `PersonsA` Table columns.

[image]

It's really getting frustrating now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible reasons:

1. Your user has actually been denied access to see the column. This can be accomplished via something as simple as:

   ```sql
    DENY SELECT ON dbo.PersonsA(Gamer_Tag) TO your_user;
   ```
2. There is more than one `PersonsA` table, and the one you are accessing in your code is actually in a different schema than `dbo`. This is why you should always, always, always specify the schema when creating or referencing objects. Always. [Read this post for more info](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).
3. Your code is connecting to a different server, a different database, or a different copy of the same database than Management Studio. (The latter can happen when using SQL Express and the `User Instance/AttachDbFileName` settings, which I can see that your code is not using, but I don't know if you are connecting to a user instance from Management Studio.)

Comment: I've not used the DENY statement at all. I've only got 1 PersonsA table and I'm connecting with a username for the server, there's no attachDbFileName.

Comment: @user3224987 Sorry, but I can't think of any other reasons why SQL Server would tell you `Column 'Gamer_Tag' does not belong to table PersonsA.` if you're connected to the right server, the right database, and there's only one such table. SQL Server doesn't invent error messages to mess with you, there's a reason, and it's very likely one of the above. Can you try by changing your code to reference `dbo.PersonsA`, please, and triple checking that the IP you're using in SSMS and `My.Settings.ServerIP` etc. are what you think they are?

Comment: There was a segment of code far back that set the table to something esle. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3224987 Can you explain? The code you showed in the question has the table hard-coded. If you dumbed the code down for us, please don't do that - it doesn't help you, nor does it help us help you.

Comment: I hadn't changed my code, but I forgot that I had set a connection string in the Public Class, for some reason it was using that. I didn't think that a section of code 'way back there' would be prevalent, and I'd had to copy and paste the entire forms code.